# Can't connect localhost to heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to get a rails app to work with heroku but I am doing something wrong.

**Database.yml**

```
   development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: (heroku db)
    user: (heroku db_user)
    pool: 5
    password: (heroku db_pass)
```

If I enter the information from my heroku database I get:

*PG::ConnectionBad FATAL: password authentication failed for user*

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why are you putting your heroku database information into your development database?

Answer (score 3):

I am not rails guy, But this is something that i have done just now on my spring app, I wanted to connect my localhost development to heroku db.. I got db info from this:

```
heroku pg:credentials DATABASE
```

then I have passed params.. But I found that to connect remote heroku db, I needed to add this to my connection params..

```
ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Comment: The old kerouku command has changed to `heroku pg:credentials:url DATABASE --app app-name`

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you also need to specify the host and port. To find out the host try running this command:

```
$ heroku config | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL
```

You should see something like

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL: postgres://user3123:passkja83kd8@ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6212/db982398
```

if you already added the PostgreSQL add-on. More on this [read here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql).

Then add the host and port info to your configuration:

```
development:
  ...
  host: ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  port: 6212
  ...
```

But do remember that it's a bad idea to work with the production database from your local dev machine, unless you really know what you are doing.